# codeigniter admin login hacked although I have used all security matters

Tags: codeigniter, admin, sql-injection

how come have the code before hacked with SQL Injection :(

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", array(mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('username')), mysql_real_escape_string(MD5($this->input->post('password')))));
```

appreciate helps!!

Comment: Hi ,

Codeigniter doing its best to serve better functionality.
The main problem with developers is that they are thinking that the users are so trust worthy.
Codeigniter giving such a nice mechanism,You need to check what the user doing.
Give a better validation through data,

You can use the Active Record class for better Queries,But you need to validate everything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use mysql_real_escape_string() as CodeIgniter Database driver does that for you. Double escaping your string could well cause some problems.

Comment: I had same hacking problem when I didnt have that mysql_real_escape_string() , and I was suggested to use that. than I added that, and I added MD5 to password, but again got hacked :(

Comment: "got hacked" is not very descriptive. Are you entirely sure it was SQL Injection, as that is very tricky to sneak through the driver class. There may well be a number of other ways to hack your system but we can't tell just from this code.

Comment: Indeed. Could have been anything - left the admin account with a default password? Set admin password to "letmein"? Virtual host hypervisor got compromised? (That's a bit over the top, I admit).

Answer (score -1):

Use like this for more safer queries:

```
    $query_username = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(username) AS count_username FROM users WHERE username=?", $this->input->post('username'));
$row_username = $query_username->row_array();
if ($row_username['count_username'] > 0) {
  $query_password = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?", $this->input->post('username'));
  $row_password = $query_password->row_array();
  if ($row_password['password'] == MD5($this->input->post('password')) {
    // LOGIN SUCCESS 
  } else {
    // LOGIN FAILED
  }
} else {
  // LOGIN FAILED
}
```